# Method not found in the .class file

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface (I.java) , which has few methods.(eg:settext())
In one of the class they have declared a variable 'x' of interface type 'I' .They are calling method settext() using x.settext().
But there is an error saying type cast. when I navigated to the interface type, it opens a I.class file and the settext() method is missing.But the I.java file still has settext() method. how do I recompile?

Comment: Re-Compile Code again !

Comment: Post your actualy code, as well as the stacktrace received.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Darshit please don't be rude or shout

Comment: Check whether you are recompiling all the Java files.

Comment: @Darshit : i have done it

Comment: Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: please do not do down votes , i will not be able to ask any questions :(

Comment: Please don't completely change the text of questions after you have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you locate where your .class file is present on your machine, then manually delete it. Go back to your IDE suppose eclipse, do a Project->Clean and try refreshing your project. Also set enable the Project->Build Automatically. Get back to the project hierarchy in your IDE and check for the freshly generated .class file, should be updated by now. Let me know if it worked for you!